Small IC engine for large?
Can we use small IC engine to start a Big car or Scooter and even use it with dynamo for spark plug? Is it better than recharging a battery ( price) ? What is minimum price of small ic engine for demo?

You'll need more specifically targeted questions in order to avoid closure of your post. In general, your question's answer is no. Nothing is going to be more efficient than a conventional alternator or if you're going bare minimums, magnetos provide spark but have other considerations and compromises.

Caterpillar used what they called a pony engine (gasoline powered), which did two things. First, the pony engine was started and ran in cold weather for a while. Coolant was shared between it and the main large diesel engine which would actually power the equipment. The pony engine would heat the coolant, which would heat the diesel engine. Once everything was warm, the pony engine was used as the starter for the diesel engine to get it running. Cat no longer uses this starting method, I assume because you had to have two different fuel types to keep things running.

You still need a battery on a modern vehicle to keep its systems active. In the old days a battery on an unused car might keep its charge for months (with no demand on it), but now it is only weeks. And a battery + starter motor (which in some cases doubles as a generator) is simpler than duplicating a smaller ICE.

As @Paulster2 mentioned, pony engines used to be a thing on large equipment like bulldozers and shovels, but are no longer used due to cost and complexity. The concept does work and was used on actual equipment in the past, but it is not economical or sensible in the modern day with current battery technology. Back when they were used, it was for very large diesel engines, which were difficult or impossible to cold start with even 6 or 8 6-volt lead-acid batteries of the day.
